# Compress GTiff External Overviews with GDAL API

Tags: gdal, gdal-python-binding, map-overviews

Is it possible to build compressed external overviews with the `gdal` API? I see examples of using `gdaladdo` with a `COMPRESS_OVERVIEW` option passed to the configure flag, but I don't see an equivalent in the GDAL API for the `BuildOverviews` function.

For reference, I'm using the Python bindings (though don't mind C++) like this:

```
# open read-only to build external overviews
raster = gdal.OpenEx(raster_path, gdal.OF_RASTER | gdal.OF_READONLY)
raster.BuildOverviews('average', xrange(1, 10))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can do that as follows:

```
raster = gdal.OpenEx(raster_path, gdal.OF_RASTER | gdal.OF_READONLY)    
gdal.SetConfigOption('COMPRESS_OVERVIEW', 'DEFLATE')
raster.BuildOverviews("average", xrange(1, 10))
```

Comment: Any way to build internal overviews? I've tried 

from osgeo import gdal
InputImage = r"D:\image.tif"

Image = gdal.Open(InputImage,1)
Image.BuildOverviews("AVERAGE", [2,4,8,16,32,64])

Comment: @fpolig01 you just need to open the file in read-write mode. I did it like this: `gdal.Open(raster_path, 1)`

Comment: @dr_times is there a way to set the config option in BuildOverviews itself?